# nearest neighbor in 2D, a special case

Tags: algorithm, nearest-neighbor

i am trying to deal with the following problem,

saying, in a unit square space, (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), and (1, 0), inside the square there are too many points (which makes pair-wise distance calculation not wisely)

my goal is to find among those points in the square, the 1 point which is closest to a point outside the square, the point outside the square could be anywhere, as long as it is outside the square

is there an efficient algorithm to find such point inside the square, given that you know all the 2D coordinates of the points inside the square which are fixed points, and of course the point outside the square

this is not a hobby project and i have reduced the whole problem into this single problem i wish to conquer

thank you very much all indeed for chip in your ideas

Comment: Build a quadtree or kd-tree...

Comment: How efficient do you need it to be?  A voronoi tessellation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) would suffice for your problem.

Comment: Are you saying that you want a sub-linear Time complexity for this problem?

Comment: i am trying to avoid pre-building such a tree structure, the whole problem has a lot of such square unit, although points inside the squares are fixed, i really do not want to build such a tree for every unit square, building a tree for all points then the problem become a kd-tree problem, which i tried to find a new way, using a more generic data structure

Comment: i hope to find some rules, based on the query point outside the square  in relation to the square, without looking at all points inside the unit square, just few of them, then i can shrink the number of point i need to check to a manageable amount, saying 20-100, rather than 10^5

Comment: keep dividing the unit square is doable and easily enough to be done, but then

Comment: Request for clarification: In your description, you say that you have "a point" outside the square. But it seems implied that you're going to have a bunch of points outside the square, and you want to perform the "nearest point in square" query for each one of them. Is that correct? I was thinking about a similar problem recently, and had an approach in mind. It's based on quadtrees, though, which you're suggesting in a previous comment is not very appealing to you.

Comment: well, the 10^5 points inside the unit square is not necessarily uniformly distributed, i have simplified the problem to consider just one query point outside of the unit square, the outside point's position could be any in relation to the unit square, i wish to find a rule to make the task manageable, the task is to find the point or points inside the unit square which has or have the shortest distance to the query point

Comment: it is certainly true you do not have to test all points inside the unit square, possibly only the points closest to the edge or corner which is also closest to the query point, but i need to think of a robust rule to cover all situations, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help you:
Imagine the square: You have the coordinates (x,y) of the point outside the square.
1st scenario:
- You can divide square to 4 pieces (4 smaller squares).
- You have the latitude (height or `y` coordinate) and longitude (`x` coordinate)of outside point.
- based on `x` and `y` of outside point **one divided square of all 4 squares** is more near to the point (not exactly but mainly)!
- You can check just the points inside that square (reducing calculations to a quarter).

2nd scenario:
- You divide the square to more squares to increase precision and decrease calculations.

Comment: saying, the unit square is the same, (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1), but the query point is (-3, -2), i am not sure your division will help

Comment: Why not?  (-3,-2) is closer to 3rd inner square [(0,0),(0,0.5),(0.5,0.5),(0.5,0)]. Even you can narrow the search inside [(0,0),(0,0.25),(0.25,0.25),(0.25,0)] at first. This is simple. and then extend the search. something like scanning the unit square by smaller one small square starting from nearest point. This is simple. Got it?

Comment: i see, thank you very much, i am on the similar track, the query point can be roughly categorized into three classes, horizontal edge, vertical edge and corner, and then i need to find the scanning pattern, saying, the corner one, the first point, distance between it and the query point would be the smallest to any other point of either same column or same row, i need to refine the rules , thanks a lot

Comment: Your welcome. You can thank me by accepting the answer. Anyway this would be the right and better way :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a smaller square, say 0.025 by 0.025. Slide it along the inner circumference of the unit square until you find the position where it is closest to the external point. Test all points inside the smaller square to find which is the closest to the external point and choose that one.

You say there are ~10^5 points in the circle and you want to fully test ~60. For a unform density of points that equates to a small square of ~0.025 per side - good guess on my part.

Comment: thanks, probably i should give the sliding square a try

Comment: Thanks. The small square could be slid along a grid of 0.025/2 to find the closest position. Calculations for the small squares movement about a unit square could be partially cached and used again for other unit squares. If calcs are too much for a 0.025 square directly then you could start with finding the closest 0.05 square and its two neighbours then find the closest 0.025 square but slide it along only that part of the inner unit square in the three closest 0.05 unit squares. Trades complexity for possibly fewer overall calcs. P.s. if you appreciate the idea then please vote up, thanks.